# phpmyadmin display source code on Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, phpmyadmin, apache2

On VPS I have phpmyadmin on Apache2.
On every computer and IE n my computer works fine, but on Chrome on my computer it shows the source code of phpmyadmin index. Why? Is there any settings or what?
This is just happening only on this page on Chrome on my PC.

Comment: The default for FF and IE is to execute PHP automatically, but you have to set chrome to do this manually.... either that or you're not pointing chrome to the web url, but directly to the php file

Comment: "*The default for FF and IE is to execute PHP automatically*" when did browsers start executing php ?

Comment: @Dagon - my bad sense of humour

Comment: @MarkBaker since every answer i have ever seen you post is 200% correct, i was starting to get scared ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "shows the source code of phpmyadmin index" you are describing implies that your apache cannot run the php file. This can be happen for 3 reasons

1. You are pointing your web browser to the folder `something/` and apache does not know that it has to search for the `index.php` file. Fix your apache configuration or point directly your web browser to this file `something/index.php`
2. Your apache is not configured to use the php interpeter
3. You don't have php installed to your machine

Comment: going directly is the way out. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. If this solution worked out for you, please mark the anwser as correct to help other users having the same problem. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Think that found solution, but don't know what cause it. 
I used CCleaner to clean all Chrome browser data 
- the simplest solution xD